# $f$ continuous, $f_a:x\mapsto f(a+x)-f(x)$ polynomial for all a. Show that $f$ is polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, continuity

> > Let $f$ be a real continuous function such that $f(a+x) - f(x)$ is polynomial for all real $a$. Show that $f$ is polynomial.

I tried without success showing that $f$ is differentiable over $\mathbb{R}$, I also tried to use the fact that $\sum_{i=0}^n i^k $ is a polynomial in $n$ to write $f(ka)$ as a polynomial for fixed $a$ but it didn't bring much.

Lastly, I noticed that their exists an integer $N$ and a non trivial interval $]a,b[$ such that all of the polynomials $f_c$ are of degree $n$ for $c\in ]a,b[$ but I don't know how to use that.

Any hints are welcome ! Thanks

Comment: Is it $f_a$ is a polynomial, as in title, or $f_a$ is continuous, as in question?  The latter does not imply $f$ is a polynomial.

Comment: Of course you meant to say that $f_a$ is a **polynomial** for each $a$. If I remember right, De Bruijn proved a whole bunch of results like this: if $f$ is continuous and $x\mapsto f(a+x)-f(a)$ has some property for each $a$, then $f$ has the property.

Comment: Thanks, corrected ! I'll have a look at De Bruijn

Comment: Is $f(x + a) - f(x)$ a polynomial in $x$, $a$, or both $x$ and $a$?

Comment: [Bruijn, de, N. G. (1951). Functions whose differences belong to a given class. Nieuw Archief voor Wiskunde,serie 2, 23, 194-218.](https://pure.tue.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/4316577/597498.pdf) From p. 203: "The class $C_4$ consisting of all polynomials has the difference property."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f_a(x)$ is a polynomial in $x$ of degree $n \ge 1$, and $b \ne 0$, then $f_a(x+b) - f_a(x) = f(x+a+b) - f(x+a) - f(x+b) + f(x)$ is a polynomial in $x$ of degree $n-1$.  But note that this is also $f_b(x+a) - f_b(x)$.  This implies that all the polynomials $f_a(x)$ for $a \ne 0$ have the same degree.  Similarly, the leading coefficient of $f_a(x)$ must be $ac$ where $c$ is the same for all $a \ne 0$.

Now let $g(x) = f(x) - c x^{n+1}/(n+1)$.  Then $g_a(x) = f_a(x) - c \frac{(x+a)^{n+1} - x^{n+1}}{n+1}$.  $g$ has the same property as $f$, except
$g_a(x)$ has lower degree than $f_a(x)$.  In a finite number of steps, we get
to a continuous function $h$ where $h_a(x)$ is constant for each $a$.  That constant is
$h_a(0) = h(a) - h(0)$. From this we can prove that $h$ is a polynomial of degree $\le 1$, and working backwards we get that $f$ is a polynomial.